# JavaFX Application Name does not show up in Task Manager or Dock

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I created a JavaFX app and have set window titles. The stage itself has a title, however when I hover over the icon in the dock or view task-manager while running the app I get the package name for the class.

Example:

[image: Blue box shows the tooltip that's the problem.]

How do I show stage title when I hover over the icon instead of showing the package name (authentication.EmployeeLogin in this case)?

The application was deployed for windows using Launch4J.

Comment: Has the application been deployed to a native executable?

Comment: @zephyr yes i deployed it using launch 4j

Comment: Did you set your application name when deploying? I am not familiar with Launch4J, but you may have missed a step there. Just setting the title within Java itself isn't enough, you have to set the title for your executable as well.

Comment: @zephyr, you were right. I had to install the latest version of Launch4J and then set the title in Launch4J. Thank you. Can you post your comment so I can accept it as an answer?

Comment: Done. Could you also please add to your question that the application was deployed using Launch4J? That will help others with the same issue find your question and the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have set the titles for your windows within your Java code, you need to do the same for the executable itself when deploying your application.

Check your Launch4J parameters when building your native executable.